# How to remove duplicate properties in LESS

Tags: css, less

I have a little LESS code:

```
.text-wraper {
  width: 50%;
  height:200px;
  h2 {
    margin: 10px 15px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

.sucess-wraper-header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  &,
  .text-wraper,
  h2 {
    margin: 10px 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    span {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that there is a little duplication i.e.

```
h2 {
    margin: 10px 15px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
```

we can putt outside the wrappers. But we have different styling for the h2. Can we remove this duplication in LESS?

Thanks

Comment: try like `.text-wraper h2, .sucess-wraper-header h2{margin: 10px 15px; padding: 0px;}`

Comment: What operator would be used in LESS to minimize number of lines in LESS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mixin these properties:

```
.heading() {
margin: 10px 15px;
padding: 0px;
}

.text-wraper {
  width: 50%;
  height:200px;
  h2 {
    .heading();
  }
}

.sucess-wraper-header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  &,
  .text-wraper,
  h2 {
    .heading();
    span {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```